# How to get the email of the user in facebook c# sdk

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using https://github.com/sanjeevdwivedi/facebook-csharp-sdk to integrate facebook in my wp8 app.
I want to know how to access the user email id using facebook-csharp-sdk below is the code I am using

```c#
FacebookSession session = FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient(session.AccessToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.access_token = session.AccessToken;
parameters.fields = "email,first_name,last_name";
dynamic result = await _fb.GetTaskAsync("me", parameters);
```

But I am getting only firstname , lastname and id of the logged in `result` field. Please suggest where am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask for the email permission.

`FacebookSession session = FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream,email");`

The last item in the `LoginAsync` params I placed is `email`

See [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) for more info